# Spring Cloud Stream Kafka Producer messages

Tags: java, spring, apache-kafka, spring-cloud-stream, spring-kafka

I want to setup a spring-cloud-stream-kafka producer with spring boot.

The producer is working and I can consume the messages from the kafka broker but the messages also contain some header information like the following:

```
contentType   "text/plain"originalContentType    "application/json;charset=UTF-8"{"message":"hello"}
```

My POJO contains one field (String message) so I'm expecting that only the JSON string will be send to kafka.

The method test() in my RestController triggers the producer:

```
@EnableBinding(ProducerChannels.class)
@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
public class KafkaStreamProducerApplication {

private MessageChannel consumer;

public KafkaStreamProducerApplication(ProducerChannels channels) {
    this.consumer = channels.consumer();
}

@PostMapping("/test/{message}")
public void test(@PathVariable String message) {
    Message<MyMessage> msg = MessageBuilder.withPayload(new MyMessage(message)).build();
    this.consumer.send(msg);
}

interface ProducerChannels {

    @Output
    MessageChannel consumer();
}
```

My application.properties

```
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.consumer.destination=consumer
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.consumer.content-type=application/json
```

I would also appreciate if you can recommend any docs or examples on this topic. The examples on [github](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-samples) are usually really thin, they use a lot of auto configuration and no explanations. The example I used was for RabbitMQ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to avoid embedding the headers (so you can receive messages in some non-Spring Cloud Stream app), set the producer's `headerMode` to `raw`.

See [Producer Properties](http://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/Chelsea.SR2/reference/htmlsingle/index.html#_producer_properties).

> **headerMode**
>
> When set to raw, disables header embedding on output. Effective only for messaging middleware that does not support message headers natively and requires header embedding. Useful when producing data for non-Spring Cloud Stream applications.
>
> Default: embeddedHeaders.

Comment: Was pretty sure that I tried this without success. Maybe I didn't restart the server because I forgot to include devtools :(. Thank you for the right answer and the link to the docs.

Answer (score 0):

The `contentType` and `originalContentType` headers are used by Spring Cloud Stream when deserializing the message by the consumer application and perform message conversion based on the content-type set.

The `contentType` header is explicitly set only when you configure the bindings's content-type as you did it here `spring.cloud.stream.bindings.consumer.content-type=application/json`.
When the `contentType` header is set, Spring Cloud Stream preserves this header using the `originalContentType` flag during serialization/de-serialization process of producing/consuming messages to/from the broker (via binder).

In your case, I guess you may not need to set the `contentType` at all.

For the examples apart from the samples in that spring-cloud-stream-samples github repo, you can also refer [out of the box app starters](https://github.com/spring-cloud-stream-app-starters) which cover wide range of applications that could run against any of the supported binders (including Kafka).